# How can you check to see if your theorem already exists?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots

Recently i created a theorem, but it has a very high chance that its already been discoverd, hence i would like to check to see if it has but have no idea how to. Being a student without any connections to universitites or professors, i dont know how to check if my theorems already exist.

Hence i ask if anyone knows how i could see if my theorem are new, please let me know. Also for any calculus proffessors please tell me if you have heard of the following theorem:

For a polyonmial of degree n and of the form y=ax^n+bx^(n-1)+…+dx+e has n roots being q_1,q_2,…,q_n (where q_i means q subscript i). If x is the arithmetic mean between the roots,that is x=(q_1+q_2+…+q_n)/n then the n-1 th derivitive is 0 (so if you do the derivtive n-1 times, you get the result to be 0)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It follows from Vieta's theorem.

Comment: How so? Veiteas theorem is just roots of polynomials, and i used thay method to porve the result. Do you mean i used veitas theorem to porve the result? Or my theorem is a direct copy of vietas theorem

Comment: Explaining @MichaelHoppe's hint: prove $y^{(n-1)}=(n-1)!(nax+b)$, which is $0$ at $x=-\frac{b}{na}$. But the roots of $y$ sum to $-\frac{b}{a}$.

Comment: @Mahfuz: While perhaps the commenters might wish to speak for themselves, I believe that the point of the comments is that your theorem may be regarded as a basic exercise in the application of Vieta's Theorem.